# Android Does excludeFromRecents require any permission?

Tags: android

When I write `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` or `android:noHistory="true"`, it doesn't disable recent apps on Android 4.0+ tablets. Does it require any permission or minSdkVersion or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> When I write android:excludeFromRecents="true" or android:noHistory="true", it doesn't disable recent apps on Android 4.0+ tablets.

Neither is supposed to "disable recent apps".

`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`, defined on the `<activity>` that will form the root of a task, [will prevent that activity's task from appearing in the recent-tasks list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude).

`android:noHistory="true"` means that [the activity is `finish()`-ed whenever the user leaves it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist), by any mechanism.